# Command line java, file argument and piped input

Tags: java, command-line, arguments, pipe

I'm working on a program and I'd like it to function like this

```
my_program -o Words
```

Where "Words" is a file, but I'd also like it to function with piped input not from a file, so

```
grep test Words | my_program -o
```

How do I collect and store that piped in data? How can I check if data has been piped in?

Comment: "a programming assignment" as in homework?

Comment: Valuable info, but remember that the [tag:homework] tag is banned. @foampile

Answer (score 1):

To read piped data you should read from stdin in your program.

`grep test Words | my_program -o`

In your example `|` pipes the stdout of `grep test Words` into stdin of `my_program`. See  [article on streams, pipes, and redirects](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lpic1-v3-103-4/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

piped in data can be read from `System.in` using standard tools like `Scanner`, `BufferedInputReader` etc.

Rather than checking for piped-in input, it would probably be easier to check the opposite condition: if a file has been specified as an argument, and if it hasn't been, then read from standard input

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

- `System.in` "is" stdin;
- `System.out` "is" stdout;
- `System.err` "is" stderr.

By using a pipe, you redirect stdin, therefore `foo | bar` redirects whatever `foo` outputs to stdout into `bar`'s stdin.

`System.in` is an `InputStream`. If you want to have the possibility to read from stdin as well as a file, one possibility is to do that:

```
InputStream in = System.in;

if (hasOptionToReadFromFile)
    in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName));
```